# VI Regular Expressions - Replacing using current line number

Tags: regex, vim

I'm not sure it's possible or not, but one of the things I find I need to do often is to replace the contents of the file, but I want to use the current line number as a replacement option.  So if I had a file like:

```
This is text to replace XX 
This is text to replace XX 
This is text to replace XX
```

I would want to be able to run a regex that would turn that file into:

```
This is text to replace 1
This is text to replace 2
This is text to replace 3
```

I've looked around, but I can't seem to find any way of doing this.  Is this possible? Does anyone know of a simple way to approach this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
:help sub-replace-expression
```

You can construct a replace expression like:

```
:s@ xx$@\=" " . line(".")@
```

... Which works for me.

Comment: what is that magic with '@'. I moved through help and this is still isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks, that's just about the exact thing I was looking for.  In my case, the expression I was looking for was:

:%s/XX/\=line(".")/g

Works like a charm.

Comment: Whatever non-alphanumeric character follows s is used as the delimiter of expressions. That @ could as easily be a comma, period, #, ", !, or ¥ as it could be /

Comment: Thanks Greyfade, I was able to simplify a bit: `:s/XX/\=line(".")/` or `:%s/XX/\=line(".")/` to run against every line. To only match end of lines, of course: `:%s/XX$/\=line(".")/`. Your way is more flexible by demonstrating the concatenation of patterns in the replacment tho.

Comment: Wow, this answer just changed my life. I've been using vi/vim for 20 years, and never knew you could use alternate delimeters with the substitute command. Thanks greyfade!

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier approach

```
:%s/dummy/\=printf("dummy%d", line('.'))
```

The above regular expression in vi appends line number to each dummy word:

From

```
dummy
dummy
dummy
```

To:

```
dummy1
dummy2
dummy3
```